# Where can I find a bard singing "Three Hearts as One?"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So I found this bard song on Youtube and I really like it.

This would be the song by the way.

But now I want to listen to it in game (the main reason is because I wonder what it sounds like in german) and I wonder where I can find a bard that plays this song. Can It be found in every tavern or only in a certain city. Also does it even exist in other languages besides english because I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is a rather patriotic tune about the formation of the Ebonheart Pact, so firstly, you're gonna need to be in one of their cities. It's just not the sort of thing a Covenant or Dominion bard is ever gonna sing.

Beyond that, it should be possible to hear it in basically every tavern where someone sings; all the bard songs in the game were recorded by numerous voice actors, so every bard voice can sing every possible song. You may, however, need to wait a short while for that particular song to come up.

The first place where I can outright guarantee that the song plays, is in Davon's Watch, the city you initially spawn in upon leaving the tutorial as a Pact character. The tavern there, known as The Watch House, has a bard singing in the kitchen area on the right, and she does occasionally sing Three Hearts As One. It's right near the temple/mages guild, and across the street from a bank.

Unfortunately, I don't know how they handled translating the songs; the German version may be completely different.